# Varargs function with optional arguments

Tags: julia, variadic-functions, optional-parameters

I have a script `foo.jl` with a function that can take 4 arguments, 2 of which are optional. I can do this easily with

```
function bar(a, b, c=1, d=2)
    println(a, b, c, d)
end

bar(ARGS[1], ARGS[2], ARGS[3], ARGS[4])
```

I can call this with arguments from the terminal with

```
$:> julia foo.jl 1 2 3 4
1234
```

But if I wanted to only specify the first two arguments `a` and `b`, with `c=1` and `d=2`, I wouldn't be able to call the script with `$:> julia foo.jl 1 2` since the script doesn't contain a function call with 2 arguments. A work around is to measure the length of `ARGS` in `foo.jl` and conditionally call `bar`:

```
if length(ARGS) == 2
    bar(ARGS[1], ARGS[2])
elseif length(ARGS) == 3
    bar(ARGS[1], ARGS[2], ARGS[3])
else
    bar(ARGS[1], ARGS[2], ARGS[3], ARGS[4])
end
```

But this is a bit bulky when moving beyond 4 arguments. So I looked at using variable arguments, where I could call an arbitrary number of arguments with

```
function bar(a, b, x...)
    println(a, b, x)
end

bar(ARGS[1], ARGS[2], ARGS[3:end])
```

calling this in multiple ways

```
$:> julia foo.jl 1 2
12(String[],)
$:> julia foo.jl 1 2 3 4
12(["3", "4"],)
$:> julia foo.jl 1 2 3 4 5 6
12(["3", "4", "5", "6"],)
```

But then I don't know how (or if I'm able) to set a default for `x...` if it's not provided in terminal. Something naive like `function bar(a, b, x...=(1, 2))` does not work. A solution here would be to set the variables inside the function depending on the contents or size of `x...`. But I don't know if there is a better way to do this.

So I'm looking for a way to call a function using arguments from terminal, where a number (2 in this case) are required, while the rest are optional and set to a default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the following function:

```
function flexiargs(a1,a2,a3="3",a4="4",a5="5",a6...)
    println((a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6))
end
flexiargs(args::AbstractVector)=flexiargs(args...)
```

This function will work with any number of params provided that there are at least two of them.

Let's test with the following data:

```
args0=["one","two"]
args1=["one","two","three","four"];
args2=vcat(args,"five","six","seven")
```

Let's see how it works:

```
julia> flexiargs(args0)
("one", "two", "3", "4", "5", ())

julia> flexiargs(args1)
("one", "two", "three", "four", "5", ())

julia> flexiargs(args2)
("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", ("six", "seven"))
```

Finally note that this is also OK:

```
function flexiargs(a1,a2,a3="3",a4="4",a5="5",a6...=("6","7"))
    println((a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6))
end
flexiargs(args::AbstractVector)=flexiargs(args...)
```

In that case by default (if not enough values are in `args`) `a6` will be simply a one element `Tuple` with the only element being a `Tuple` `("6","7")`.

Comment: This did it! The key section I needed is `flexiargs(args::AbstractVector)=flexiargs(args...)`, and now I can call
`function flexiargs(a1,a2,a3...=("3","4")) println((a1,a2,a3)) end
flexiargs(args::AbstractVector)=flexiargs(args...)
`
Which is exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a default for `x...` as follows:

```
function bar(a, b, x::Vararg{Any,N}=(1,2)...) where {N}
    println(a, b, x)
end

bar(ARGS[1], ARGS[2], ARGS[3:end]...)
```

When calling `bar`, it is important to write `ARGS[3:end]...` instead of `ARGS[3:end]`. The dots result in an empty array being evaluated to zero additional arguments. Only in this case, the default will be used.

### Further considerations

Note that `x::Vararg{Any,N}` is the same as `x...` but allows you to use type constraints. For example, since `ARGS` is a String array, you might want to improve the type stability of your function by changing the default to `x::Vararg{String,N}=("1","2")...`. More detail on the `Vararg` mechanism is provided in [the Julia manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Varargs-Functions).

### Alternative solution: ArgParse

When dealing with `ARGS`, I recommend using the [ArgParse](https://argparsejl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/argparse.html) package. It provides you with command-line documentation (`julia foo.jl --help`) and with a great level of control and readability.